# npm adduser asking for one-time password from authenticator app

Tags: npm

I'm running `npm adduser` and attempting to sign in with my username and password but it's prompting me to enter the one-time password from my authenticator app. I have 2FA set up on my npm account but I'm not sure I'm using an authenticator app. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved this yesterday: I turned off 2FA and then turned it back on. Selected view the QR code, the authenticator app is a native setting in iPhones

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. What a pain. Thanks for the guidance.